# Can worst case time complexity of binary search be Ω(logn)?

Tags: time-complexity, binary-search

I know how people say worst-case time complexity of binary search is O(logn), but would not also saying Ω(logn) be valid?

Answer (score 0):

Ω expresses a lower bound of an algorithm's running time.
Saying that the binary search has Ω(logn) best-case performance would mean that you need *at least* `log n` steps to conclude that an element are looking is or is not present.
However, while in the worst case you need to search the entire array (log n) steps (consider for instance if the element is not present in the array), in the best case you only need a constant number of comparisons (consider for instance the case in which the element you are looking for is in the middle of the array).